# Assign event listener from js class

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to assign onclick event listener to an object from within a class
and then get some variable from the instance that created that onclick

```
function myclass() {

    this.myvar;

    this.myfunc = function() 
    {
        alert(this.myvar);
        document.onmousedown = this.mouseDown;        
    }

    this.mouseDown = function(e) 
    {
        alert(this.myvar); //does not work of course
        //how could I access myvar from current myclass instance
    }

}


var myclass_instance = new myclass();
    myclass_instance.myvar = 'value'
    myclass_instance.myfunc();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E7wK4/

Comment: What is it not doing that you expected it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the `mouseDown` event is not the `this` of the instance.

Try **this** instead:

```
function myclass() {

    var _this = this;

    this.myvar;

    this.myfunc = function() 
    {
        alert(this.myvar);
        document.onmousedown = this.mouseDown;        
    }

    this.mouseDown = function(e) 
    {
        alert(_this.myvar); //<<<<
    }

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/E7wK4/1/

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Neal you could bind this.

```
document.onmousedown = this.mouseDown.bind(this);
```